# Handling lots of FILE pointers

Tags: c, multithreading, mingw-w64

### TLDR

Is there a clean way to handle 1 to 65535 files through an entire program without allocating global variables where a lot of it is may never used and without using linked lists (mingw-w64 on windows)

### Long Story

I have a tcp-server which allocates data from a lot of clients (up to 65535) and saves them in kind of a database. The "database" is a directory/file structure which looks like this: data\%ADDR%\%ADDR%-%DATATYPE%-%UTCTIME%.wwss where %ADDR% is the Address, %DATATYPE% is the type of data and %UTCTIME% is the utc time in seconds when the first data packet arrived on this socket. So every time a new connection is accepted it should create this file as specified.

How do I handle 65535 FILE handles correctly? First thought: Global variable.

```
FILE * PV_WWSS_FileHandles[0x10000]
//...
void tcpaccepted(uint16_t u16addr, uint16_t u16dataType, int64_t s64utc) {
    char cPath[MAX_PATH];
    snprintf(cPath, MAX_PATH, "c:\\%05u\\%05u-%04x-%I64d.wwss", u16addr, u16addr, u16dataType, s64utc);
    PV_WWSS_FileHandles[u16addr] = fopen(cPath, "wb+");
}
```

This seems very lazy, as it will likely never happen that all addresses are connected at the same time and so it allocates memory which is never used.

Second thought: Creating a linked list which stores the handles. The bad thing here is, that it could be quite cpu intensive because I want to do this in a multithreading Environment and when f.e. 400 threads receive new data at the same time they all have to go through the entire list to find there FILE handle.

Comment: Have you actually tried opening 65535 files at the same time?

Comment: Can your system really have that many files open simultaneously? The hard limit on my Linux system is only 4096. Anyway, the array approach is good. Unused memory pages go out of cache so it shouldn't matter if you're not using it. Other approaches will likely have worse performance.

Comment: Ok you are right, that could lead to errors so I may save the utc time in that array and open the file when its needed, even though the file name has to be generated each time the file needs to be accessed.

Comment: Perhaps only fopen() the file at the moment you need to read/write the file, and then fclose() it again immediately afterwards?  I think that would be more likely to scale than trying to keep thousands of FILE pointers open at once.  Or better yet, don't write the data to disk at all; instead just keep it in memory?

Comment: In terms of memory, you're allocating 64K * (4 or 8 bytes per pointer) which is 256 KiB or 512 KiB.  How much memory does your machine have?  More than 1 GiB?  Thought so.  You won't notice that much memory usage.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner: The system could may reboot so the data would be lost

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: >= 4GiB, yes you are right but that's not the problem, it just feels wrong and inefficient. 
On my machine (W10) the maximum is 509 files which could open simultaneously, after that the errno is set to 24 (Too many files open)

Comment: How do you know when a connection is finished with?  If you can have only 509 files open, then you can't have a single process handling 64K clients with the files all open.  You need to be prepared to keep a list of 64K names (or, at least, the info needed to create the name), and map them to open files when possible, closing the least recently used file when necessary to get one to use.  Or some similar scheme.  You probably have a table with your 509 decriptors, which can include a pointer back to the corresponding connection.  That allows you to clean up sanely.

Comment: *I have a tcp-server which allocates data from a lot of clients (up to 65535) and saves them in kind of a database*  How about using an actual database of some type instead of reinventing the wheel?

Comment: @Andrew Helene: Like SQL? I do like optimizing my code for the special function it is used for, adding a SQL Database include would create an immensive overhead..

Comment: @GtaSpider *Like SQL? I do like optimizing my code for the special function it is used for, adding a SQL Database include would create an immensive overhead.*  Nowhere *near* the overhead of designing, coding, optimizing, and then maintaining your almost-certainly *slower* and much more bug-prone "database".  There's less overhead, effort, and risk in just using even a relatively low-end database such as MySQL. Do you really think you can beat decades of experience and the cumulative bug-discovering impact of hundreds of millions of installed instances?

Answer (score 1):

You really should look at other people's code.  Apache comes to mind.  Let's assume you can open 2^16 file handles on your machine.  That's a matter of tuning.

Now... consider first what a file handle is.  It's generally a construct of your C standard library... which is keeping an array (the file handle is the index to that array) of open files.  You're probably going to want to keep an array, too, if you want to keep other information on those handles.

If you're concerned about the resources you're occupying, consider that each open network filehandle causes the OS to keep a 4k or 8k (it's configurable) buffer x2 (in and out) along with the file handle structure.  That's easily a gigabyte of memory in use at the OS level.

When you do your equivalent of select(), if your OS is smart, you'll get the filehandle back --- so you can use that to index your array of "what to do" for that file handle.  If your select() is not smart, you'll have to check every open filehandle ... which would make any attempt at performance a laugh.

I said "look at other people's solutions."  I mean it.  The original apache used one filehandle per process (effectively).  When select()'s were dumb, this was a good strategy.  Bad in that typically, dumb OS's would wake too many processes --- but that was circa 1999.  These days apache defaults to it's hybrid MPM model... which is a hybrid of multi-threading and multi-tasking.  It services a certain number of clients per process (threads) and has multiple processes.  This keeps the number of files per process more reasonable.

If you go back further, for simplicity, there's the inetd approach.  Fork one (say) ftp process per connect.  The world's largest ftp server (ftp.freebsd.org) ran that way for many years.

Do not store file handles in files (silly).  Do not store file handles in linked lists (your most popular code route will kill you).  Take advantage of the fact that file handles are small integers and use an array.  realloc() can help here.

Heh... I see other FreeBSD people have chipped in ... in the comments.  Anyways... look up FreeBSD and kqueue() if you're going to try keeping that many things open in one process.

Comment: IIRC under Windows file handles are not small integers.